# preload with percentage - javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, progress

I did a Google search and I cannot find a way to do a loading with percentage. Anyone know how I can find an example of that?

I need a preload for a website from 0-100 without bar, before show the content, but I cannot find any example.

Comment: There's no way of telling how much content is on the page, or how much progress has been made in loading it.

Comment: it is possible, check this example http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader/

Comment: @Fel You just answered your own question, then?

Comment: but this example uses a progress bar i need something like that http://flash-templates-today.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/index110.png

Comment: Yes, but I'm pretty sure the example you linked to could be easily adapted to show percentage. EDIT: In fact, it has been: http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader2/

Comment: i found it, it is something like that, now i go investigate the code http://neverforget.us/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean you want to show the content only when it is fully loaded, you may try following two options:

1) wrap all content inside a `<div id="wrapper" style="display:none;"></div>` tag and on load complete event show it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#wrapper").show();
});
```

2) If this still does not solves your purpose, you can load empty page and fetch content using ajax:

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
        .......//AJAX params
        .......
        success:function(msg){
                    $("#wrapper").html(msg);//DO NEEDFUL WITH THE RETURNED VALUE
                });
});
```

EDIT: Using `queryLoader` script provided by [gayadesign](http://www.gayadesign.com/) I was able to achieve some success :D

I had to made some changes to the `queryLoader.js` file from line 127 to 151. The changed script is as follows. Try it yourself.

```
$(QueryLoader.loadBar).css({
        position: "relative",
        top: "50%",
        font-size:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:50px;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    });
},

animateLoader: function() {
    var perc = (100 / QueryLoader.doneStatus) * QueryLoader.doneNow;
    if (perc > 99) {
        $(QueryLoader.loadBar).stop().animate({
            width: perc + "%"
        }, 5000, "linear", function() {
                $(this).html("<strong>100%</strong>");//MY EDIT
                QueryLoader.doneLoad();
            });
    } else {
    $(QueryLoader.loadBar).stop().animate({
        width: perc + "%"
    }, 5000, "linear", function() {
            //MY EDIT
            $(this).html("<strong>"+Math.round(perc)+"%</strong>");
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: but the question is the value of the percentage, i can't put a gif in this project

Comment: Oops :( [gay(a)design] @Fel you say in last line that you want to preload without bar, so this will work in that situation. For showing percentage, I'm trying to find out something. The example you gave (gaydesign) looks promising.

Answer (score 17):

I recommend this plugin. Its amazing 
download from http://demo.inwebson.com/download/jpreloader.zip
see in action here http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jpreLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').jpreLoader();
    });
// ]]></script>
```

here are the links to new version jpreloader 2.1 
http://demo.inwebson.com/download/jpreloader-v2.zip 
http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/

Comment: It is lagging for me when I am downloading in the background a huge site, especially when the things get loaded from cached images.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.

As zzzzBov said, it isn't known how much content there will be, or what size that content is.

You could 'fake' it, with something like this (for the example I am using images):

```
var percentCounter = 0;

$.each(arrayOfImageUrls, function(index, value) {
    $('<img></img>').attr('src', value)    //load image
        .load(function() {
            percentCounter = (index / arrayOfImageUrls.length) * 100;    //set the percentCounter after this image has loaded
            $('#yourProgressContainer').text(percentCounter + '%');
        });
});
```

As I mentioned this isn't a TRUE percentage of the sites loading, but a rough estimate of the images that have loaded, assuming each image is roughly the same size.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't say you "can't", but this is my favorite solution.

Comment: I like this way. But based on my experiments, I think, the iteration using `each` wouldn't give the index values in the same sequential order. Instead, it might be random sometimes. So, instead of dividing the `index`, I used a separate variable which will increment by 1 each time and I am dividing this counter variable with the length of the array and then multiplied with 100 to obtain the percentage.

Comment: @elwyn It is showing me `Uncaught ReferenceError: arrayOfImageUrls is not defined`??

Comment: `arrayOfImageUrls ` was an example variable from your own code, you need to actually make it yourself. For example `var arrayOfImageUrls = ['https://example.com/foo.jpg', https://example.com/bar.jpg'];`

Answer (score 2):

See this Project. It does what you want nicely.

> http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/

The demo is hosted here

> http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader/

Download it here

> http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader/queryLoader.zip