# Is there some jquery plugin preloader percentage?

Tags: jquery

Is there some jquery plugin preloader percentage?

or some way to do it?

thanks.

Comment: Just google it http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/preloader

Comment: but can i use it to preloading a ajax content?

Answer (score 0):

[preload with percentage - javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999703/preload-with-percentage-javascript-jquery)  this will be a help

Comment: i'm talking about something like: jQuery.ajax({ url: 'test.php', async: false, success: function(data) { /* */ }}); i would like to show a preloader percentage while 'test.php' is loading

Comment: yes it can be done http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader2/ see the example