# How to show website loading in percentage instead of gif or any animated image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using CSS & jQuery Preloader in my website for showing preloading image untill my complete website is not downloaded.
http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/preloader/default.asp (I am using this Example).

Now I am using a Gif Image until my Complete Website is not Downloaded. Can anybody Help me to 
show loading in percentage instead of gif image.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to know how it should be done in css or to calculate the percent ? through css, you can Set the loading bar width to 0 initially and keep increasing it till the max width.

Comment: this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999703/preload-with-percentage-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Try a **HTML5 and jquery preloader**... Its a good jquery plugin for your requirement...

http://gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery-html5Loader/

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is to load parts of your website asynchronously. E.g. if you need to load some text and image, first thing you need to do is to specify how many percents should this resource take:

```
text - 15%
image - 85%
```

Then after loading text you can animate width of progress bar to 15%, and trigger loading of image. After loading image you can animate width of progress bar to 100% and show whole content.

Image load event [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424055/check-if-images-are-loaded).

Asynchronous loading of text content [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (using ajax).