# Knowing the loading percentage of an image

Tags: javascript, html

With the new improvements in HTML5, it's now possible to know the loading percentage of an image (or other files), to build a progress bar with real data?

Is at least possible to know in advance the size of an image (or other files) to fake this percentage more accurately?

All the info I found seems outdated, or perhaps it isn't possible yet. But a lot of websites shows this days percentage spinners and progress bars... how? Exists an usual fake trick?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999703/preload-with-percentage-javascript-jquery

Comment: The image itself is a visual progress bar of its own loading.

Comment: @ced-b, assuming the answer of the question linked is updated, we can deduct some answers of my question, but I think it will be interesting for me and for other people in the future to know accurate answers to the questions I ask here.

Comment: @Boann, the more important objection is: I want to preload the images, not to load them dinamically. I want it loaded and in the future I will decide to put it in the real flow of the website.

Answer (score 0):

The most loading spinners are based on the numbers of file. With this number there are calculating the percentage. I do not know one witch is calculating by the file-size.